# Using JUnit, access Application class in test case

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I'm testing my global Application in JUnit.
I have successfully setup my Application,

```
public classs TestApplication extends ApplicationTestCase<SomeApplication> {
   private SomeApplication app;
   public TestApplication(String name) {
       super(SomeApplication.class);
       setName(name);
   }

   @Override
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       super.setUp();
       createApplication();
       app = getApplication();
   }
}
```

and my question is, how do you access `TestApplication` in the test case activity like

```
public class ActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SomeActivity> {

}
```

Also, how do you access the methods of `SomeApplication`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two code snippets you provided don't work together.  Those are two separate test cases that are meant to run independently of one another.

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase has the method getActivity(), which returns your Activity, which is also a Context.  That context has getApplicationContext(), which can be cast to your Application subclass.

That is how you would access it in an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase.  Which has its own setup and teardown methods to be overridden.  The actual test runs in a method you create that starts with 'test', like

```
testSomeApplication() {}
```

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase is meant more for integration and functional tests rather than unit tests.  The device you are testing on will actually be running your app, booting into the activity that you set the test case to (SomeActivity in this case).

For more of a "unit test" of your Application subclass, you can use ApplicationTestCase.  Accessing the application instance in this case is quite simple:

```
getApplication()
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ApplicationTestCase.html#getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ApplicationTestCase.html#getApplication%28%29)

Comment: How to Unit test or create the instance of the custom Application class?